# Array equation with GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to test the GEKKO environment for solving a model with a population balance equation.

Here is a test of solving a population balance equation with birth, death and growth on a population age distribution that I coded with Gekko (below). I don't understand the mistake I'm making here.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Simulation time
tf = 50

# Number of age groups
N = 100

# Creation of the GEKKO model instance
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0, tf, 101)

# Input data
birth_rate = 0.01  # taux de natalité
death_rate = 0.02  # taux de mortalité
growth_rate = 0.005  # taux de croissance
init_dist = np.zeros(N)  # distribution initiale de la population
init_dist[40:60] = 1  # population initiale dans l'intervalle [40,60]

# Model variables
dist = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
birth = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
death = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
growth = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)

# Initial constraints
for i in range(N):
    dist[i].value = init_dist[i]

# Equation of the variables birth, death and growth
for i in range(1, N-1):
    m.Intermediate(birth[i] == birth_rate * dist[i-1])
    m.Intermediate(death[i] == death_rate * dist[i])
    m.Intermediate(growth[i] == growth_rate * dist[i])

# Equation on the dist variable
m.Equation(dist[i].dt() == birth[i] - death[i] + growth[i] for i in range(N))

# Model resolution
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=False)
```

And here is the error I encountered :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20580\1988164512.py in <module>
     42 # Résolution du modèle
     43 m.options.IMODE = 4
---> 44 m.solve(disp=False)
     45 
     46 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py in solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   2138                 print("Error:", errs)
   2139             if (debug >= 1) and record_error:
-> 2140                 raise Exception(apm_error)
   2141 
   2142         else: #solve on APM server

Exception: @error: Inequality Definition
 invalid inequalities: z > x < y
 <generatorobject<genexpr>at0x000002174009f660>
 STOPPING . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to find the error is to open the run folder with `m.open_folder()` and view the `gk_model0.apm` file in a text editor. The last equation looks suspicious:

```
    v299=((0.02)*(v99))
    v399=((0.005)*(v99))
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1133605c10>
End Equations

End Model
```

Put brackets around the expression to create an equation array.

```py
m.Equations([dist[i].dt()==birth[i]-death[i]+growth[i] for i in range(N)])
```

The degrees of freedom must be zero for simulation mode. The equations for the initial age group with `birth[0]`, `death[0]`, and `growth[0]` are undefined. Also, the equations for the last age group are undefined. This resolves the degree of freedom issue, but it may not be correct.

```py
# Equation of the variables birth, death and growth
for i in range(N):
    if i==0:
        m.Equation(birth[i]==0)
    else:
        m.Equation(birth[i] == birth_rate * dist[i-1])
    m.Equation(death[i] == death_rate * dist[i])
    m.Equation(growth[i] == growth_rate * dist[i])
```

Here is the complete model that solves successfully.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Simulation time
tf = 50

# Number of age groups
N = 100

# Creation of the GEKKO model instance
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0, tf, 101)

# Input data
birth_rate = 0.01  # taux de natalité
death_rate = 0.02  # taux de mortalité
growth_rate = 0.005  # taux de croissance
init_dist = np.zeros(N)  # distribution initiale de la population
init_dist[40:60] = 1  # population initiale dans l'intervalle [40,60]

# Model variables
dist = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
birth = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
death = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
growth = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)

# Initial constraints
for i in range(N):
    dist[i].value = init_dist[i]

# Equation of the variables birth, death and growth
for i in range(N):
    if i==0:
        m.Equation(birth[i]==0)
    else:
        m.Equation(birth[i] == birth_rate * dist[i-1])
    m.Equation(death[i] == death_rate * dist[i])
    m.Equation(growth[i] == growth_rate * dist[i])

# Equation on the dist variable
m.Equations([dist[i].dt() == birth[i] - death[i] + growth[i] for i in range(N)])

# Model resolution
#m.open_folder()
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=True)
```

The APOPT solver requires two iterations:

```
 Number of state variables:          50000
 Number of total equations: -        50000
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              0
 
 solver            3  not supported
 using default solver: APOPT
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Simulation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  8.63429E-34  2.00000E-02
    1  8.63429E-34  2.00000E-02
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   0.266199999998207      sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

The IPOPT solver also requires 2 iterations to solve the 50,000 variables and 50,000 equations.

```
Number of Iterations....: 2

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Constraint violation....:   1.1102230246251565e-16    1.1102230246251565e-16
Complementarity.........:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Overall NLP error.......:   1.1102230246251565e-16    1.1102230246251565e-16


Number of objective function evaluations             = 3
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 3
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 3
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 3
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 2
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.884
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.473

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
 
 The solution was found.
 
 The final value of the objective function is   0.000000000000000E+000
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    1.55019999999786      sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```